# Finding the equation for a data set

Tags: predictive-models, computational-statistics

I asked this question on StackOverflow and someone pointed for me to ask this here.

Lets assume that I have 3 variables: x, y, z which are integers.

I have 5000 values of each and I want to predict the 5001th (or other) value given this data set. The thing is, the values oscillate a lot so I was thinking that I could possibly find the equation of this data set computationally, and I could approximate the 5001th value using this equation.

What is the preferred way for me to do this?

Comment: Is this time series data? Or what? What are x, y and z?

Comment: agree with above. very limited information here to work from. most modeling (even ML) is based on some conceptual framework of how the data related to each other.

Comment: [Original here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861783/interpolating-for-a-large-data-set-in-java). You should not cross-post essentially the same question on different stackexchange sites. Pick one location that's best for your question and post it to that one place. If you later decide it belongs elsewhere, flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved.